# Blender to Three js - Material Color rendering Issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, blender

Using **Blender v2.78** and **Three.js**.
Exporting models in **.dae** format(collada).
Material colors appear different after importing into Three.js. Please check image links to understand the problem.
 [..Model in Blender after render..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsB7M.png)  [..Scene in three.js..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaAIa.png)

Comment: I think it was caused by different light in Blender and Three.js scene.

Comment: More details please .